# Removing "To whom correspondence should be addressed" in ACS paper template

Tags: footnotes, templates, journal-publishing

I'm a complete beginner with latex, and I'm trying to use the ACS template to write a short paper. (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/acs-publications). However, I don't want the footnote "To whom correspondence should be addressed", and it seems to be defined somewhere outside of the tex file itself, out of reach for me. How may I remove this? :o

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Apparently, that line comes from the corresponding class file (ending `.cls`).  Why do you use the ACS template?  If you plan to publish at an ACS journal, you should not change these things.  Otherwise, the easiest thing would be to find another class, e.g. `article` and `scrartcl`.

Comment: The ACS require at least one author is marked as corresponding.

Comment: Alright. I've changed to the "article" template. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\acs@author@list@star{\relax}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble will remove that footnote, but leave asterisks (`*`) after the name of the authors for which you provide an e-mail.

If you want to remove that symbol as well, simply paste

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\acs@author@list@star{\relax}
\renewcommand\acs@author@star{\relax}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

This is for the technical point, but I concur with jarauh: if you plan to submit to ACS, do *not* change this behavior. Editors generally like to have "corresponding authors" clearly listed in the articles.

Comment: I thought their template looked good, but I've taken your advice and changed to the "article" template. Thanks!